# Find all possible permutations and combinations of given no. of elements in a list using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I need to find all possible permutations and combinations of given elements without repetition of same pairs.

For example

```
list = [a,b,c]
```

Desired output is

```
[(a),(b),(c),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(a,b,c),(a,c,b),(b,a,c),(b,c,a),(c,a,b),(c,b,a)]
```

I tried `itertools` in python to get the same pairs of output but failed.
Using `itertools.permutations` the output was

```
[abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba]
```

Using `itertools.combinations` the output was

```
[(), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

which missed the pairs like `(b,a)`
.

Using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` give repetitive elements within the pair, e.g.  `(a,a,a),(b,b,b)`, which is not acceptable.

The desired output should not contain repetitive pair elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`permutations` allows you to specify the length of the list of permutations:

If you include the null set:

```
permlist = []

for i in range(len(mylist) + 1):
    permlist += itertools.permutations(mylist, i)
```

If you excludethe null set:

```
permlist = []

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    permlist += itertools.permutations(mylist, i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = set()
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(len(L)+1):
    for c in itertools.combinations(L, i):
        for p in itertools.permutations(c):
            answer.add(p)

In [288]: answer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[288]: 
{(),
 ('a',),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c', 'b'),
 ('b',),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c', 'a'),
 ('c',),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b', 'a')}
```

Comment: You don't need three loops, nor do you need a `set` (it produces no duplicates). Just initialize `answer = []` and replace the two inner loops with `for p in itertools.permutations(L, i): answer.append(p)`. All full-length permutations of all combinations of a given length is equivalent to all permutations of a given length already.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: oh yeah! thanks for the reminder. Clearly, the coffee isn't working ;)